# How do i represent the chromosome using Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, scheduling, genetic-algorithm

My task is to calculate clashes between alert time schedule and the user calendar schedule to generate the clashes less alert time schedule.
How should i represent the chromosome according to this problem?
How should i represent the time slots? (Binary or Number)

Thank You
(Please Consider i'm a beginner to the genetic algorithm studies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Questions would be: What have you tried so far? How good are your results so far? Also your Problem is
>   stated quite unspecific. Thus here is what I can give:

1. The Chromosome should probably be the starttime of the alerts in your schedule (if I understood your Problem correctly).
2. As important is to think of the ways you want to evaluate and calculate the Fitness of your individuals (here clashes (e.g. amount or time overlap between appointments), but it is obvious that you might find better heuristics to receive better solutions / faster convergence)
3. Binary or continuous number might both work: I am usually going for numbers whenever there is no strong reason to not do so (since it is easier to Interpret, debug, etc.). Binary comes with some nice opportunities with respect to Mutation and Recombination.

I strongly recommend playing around and reading about those Things. This might look like a lot of extra work to implement, but you should rather come to see them as hyperparameters which Need to be tuned in order to receive the best Outcome.

Comment: Sir, the thing is i have to generate a alert schedule for water drinking time. Actually I am going to assume that, user to give alerts for the cover the daily target when user free time. So first i thought to get the user schedule and adjust the alert schedule. as well i thought to give the time slot to a drinking amount and calculate the fitness. still studying related notes.glad if you can give me related advice.